# TDS timed out getting sitecore items

Tags: sitecore, tds

I've inherited a Sitecore project and am attempting to use TDS [Get Sitecore Items] with a new TDS project however I'm running into the following error. It's worth nothing that I get a warning before the error saying

**Old Connector**

```
---------------------------
Hedgehog Development TDS
---------------------------
Warning: The version of the sitecore connector is from an older version of TDS.

Click OK to install the latest version of the connector.
```

However I've even manually removed the Sitecore connector so I'm not sure why it's detecting an older version either.

**Get Sitecore Items Error**

```
---------------------------
Hedgehog Development TDS
---------------------------
Error The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 00:01:59.9912110. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.(TimeoutException) getting sitecore items.

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.SitecoreConnector.TdsServiceSoap.CheckAccessGuid(CheckAccessGuidRequest request)
   at HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.SitecoreConnector.TdsServiceSoapClient.HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.SitecoreConnector.TdsServiceSoap.CheckAccessGuid(CheckAccessGuidRequest request)
   at HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.SitecoreConnector.TdsServiceSoapClient.CheckAccessGuid(String accessGuid)
   at HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.Utils.Support.GetTdsServiceSoapClient(SitecoreProjectNode project, Boolean checkVersion)
   at HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.Dialogs.GetSitecoreItems.LoadSitecoreItemsIntoTree(TreeNodeCollection nodes, String sitecoreBrowsePath, SitecoreItemNode node, Boolean isRoot, Boolean getAllChildren)
   at HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.Dialogs.GetSitecoreItems.GetSitecoreItems_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

It's also with nothing that while I think the error message says 1:59 minutes the error is instant and changes by a few MS on retry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you browse to the Sitecore user interface?  I've seen this error before when TDS can't communicate with Sitecore.

In our case, the issue was that the application pool for the site was using the 2.0 Framework instead of the 4.0 Framework.

Comment: Turns out the URL I was using didn't match the hostname I was expecting. I have multiple bindings one for the website and a second for the default Sitecore site.

Comment: So it was the project URL on the TDS project?

Answer (score 1):

The TDS addin communicates with Sitecore via WCF. You can fiddle with the binding configuration the followering places:

**Visual Studio 2010**

"HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.dll.config" and "HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP2010.dll.config" both located under "C:\Program Files (x86)\Hedgehog Development\Team Development for Sitecore (VS2010)"

**Visual Studio 2012**

"HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP.dll.config" and "HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.VSIP2012.dll.config" both located under "C:\Program Files (x86)\Hedgehog Development\Team Development for Sitecore (VS2012)"

I keep all of my four config files in sync where I change all timeout related values to 30 minutes and all size related values to "2147483647" (Max).

**Remember to restart Visual Studio after saving the above files.**

Comment: I bumped up the timeout to 35 minutes and restarted VS12. The error changed from `after 00:01:59.9912110` to `after 00:34:59.6713121`.

Comment: Try to use fiddler to see what TDS is trying to do, could lead you in the right direction. Or add your own implementation wrapping the service in /_DEV/TdsService.asmx and attach a debugger to see whats happening.

Answer (score 0):

The "Old Connector" message seems to always happen, no matter how many times I've updated my connector.  I am fairly certain this is just a bug in the IDE plugin where the first time it synchronizes after Visual Studio opens it needs to make itself know that the plugin is up to date.  I have no concrete data on this, but after the initial sync it stops warning me about the connector.

Regarding the timeout, you may want to verify that the TDS project configurations map up to your environment (project URL, paths, database connection strings).

Comment: I've double checked my settings and they are all correct. I also can't sync due to the timeout error.

Answer (score 0):

If your application setup is correct, then this exception is because your SQL server service is not started.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  For me it was a connection issue to the database.  check your TDS connection settings :).